# How to get height

Tags: jquery, css

I need to get `height` of the `#div1` and change css `padding-top` of `#div2`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
</div>

<div id="div2">
  change padding top
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var h = $('.div1').height();
$('.div2').css({"padding-top" : "hpx"});
```

Comment: I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

use `$("#div1")` as div1 is Id not a class

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var h = $('#div1').height(); // get height of div using .height()
    $('#div2').css("padding-top" , h+"px"); // concatenate h with + in css
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
</div>

<div id="div2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#div2').css({"padding-top" : $('#div1').height()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use only `$('#div1').css({"padding-top" : h});`

*Note that you have `id` in HTML but you are using `class` in JavaScript.*

```js
$(function() {
   var h = $('#div1').height();
   $('#div2').css({"padding-top" : h});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero porro neque placeat explicabo dolore suscipit sapiente saepe non harum. Quod neque ipsum veniam autem tempora laboriosam, asperiores quasi rem amet!
</div>

<div id="div2">
  change padding top
</div>
```